Issue Creating Google Forms Options Using Apps Script & Google Sheets
I'm using Google Sheets to create dropdown options for a google form.
I have two columns that I want to concatenate into one option, lets say first and last name.
A list of first names are in Column A and the last names are in Column B. I've created a named range for the two rows called 'firstLast'. I want to create a variable  that is a list of the first names and last names combined corresponding to there row. I tried this and I just get a list of first and last names using this code:
var nameRange = sheet.getRange('firstLast').getValues();
var nameList = nameRange.flat().filter(String);

console.log(nameList);

Any advice would be appreciated and be gentle I'm new to Apps Script and coding.
I tried using:
var nameRange = sheet.getRange('firstLast').getValues();
var nameList = nameRange.filter(String);

console.log(nameList);

but that still returns all the empty cells for some reason.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a [mcve]. In the case of Google Apps Script projects that read data from a spreadsheet, briefly describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet. If the script reads data from the spreadsheet, add some sample values. Please be clear about the data type (text/string, number, boolean or date)

If you wish to get a range by name you need to use the Spreadsheet Class getRangeByName() method

If column A is first name and B is last name then here is an array with first space last
function myFunko1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const fns = sh0.getRange(2, 1, sh0.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues().map(r => `${r[0]} ${r[1]}`);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(fns));
}

